# Python remove common word from list

Tags: python

I need to remove common word from the list. The word which need to be removed is `IPNetwork`.

```
IP_list = [IPNetwork('10.60.252.0/23'),
 IPNetwork('10.60.254.0/23'),
 IPNetwork('10.208.0.0/15'),
 IPNetwork('10.208.64.80/28'),
 IPNetwork('10.208.152.0/24'),
 IPNetwork('10.208.153.0/24'),
 IPNetwork('10.208.154.0/24'),
 IPNetwork('10.208.155.128/25'),
 IPNetwork('10.208.156.0/24')]
```

expected result:

```
['10.60.252.0/23',
 '10.60.254.0/23',
 '10.208.0.0/15',
 '10.208.64.80/28',
 '10.208.152.0/24',
 '10.208.153.0/24',
 '10.208.154.0/24',
 '10.208.155.128/25',
 '10.208.156.0/24']
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted result? Please provide code.

Comment: Is the first part input text to parse or code for setting up sample data in a data structure?

Comment: Is `IP_list` a Python list? Is `IPNetwork` a Python class or function? Or is the complete input just text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IPNetwork` is a class and you are instantiating objects of it. If you just want the ip addresses in string format, convert them to string explicitly

Using a `map`

```
>>> list(map(str, IP_list))
['10.60.252.0/23', '10.60.254.0/23', '10.208.0.0/15', '10.208.64.80/28', '10.208.152.0/24', '10.208.153.0/24', '10.208.154.0/24', '10.208.155.128/25', '10.208.156.0/24']
```

Or using list comprehension

```
>>> [str(ip) for ip in IP_list]
['10.60.252.0/23', '10.60.254.0/23', '10.208.0.0/15', '10.208.64.80/28', '10.208.152.0/24', '10.208.153.0/24', '10.208.154.0/24', '10.208.155.128/25', '10.208.156.0/24']
```

Comment: While using map over a list. Convert to a list is not necessary.

Comment: @RahulKP. What you said is true for python2. But in python3, `map` returns a `map object` in python3. So just for compatibility reasons, it is better to convert it to a list when you need a list